# How do we add two divs side by side in html

Tags: html, css

I want to add two divisions side by side, on one side I want to add the profile picture and on the other side I want to add the content like username, email etc. How can I achieve this in custom HTML and CSS?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Read [How much research efforts are expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/18254155)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and post a [mre] of the code you've attempted so we can better assist you! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a single div as a wrapper then inside that div you can use the two divs side by side. use the following code:

```html
<div class="abc">
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div style="width: 20%; float: left;">Profile - Pic</div>
<div style="width: 80%; float: left;">Name : abc
Email : useremail
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The div's will float, and therefor not best practice for a div structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```css
.ava {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {width: 90px}
```

```html
<div class="ava">
  <div class="image"> <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/mysterious-mafia-man-smoking-cigarette_52683-34828.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1744368405.1645544000" /> </div>
  <div class="content"> Kite </div>
</div>
```

you can check this ->